# Choose departments from a list that don't have active users

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a database with tables `'departments'`, `'branches'` and `'staff'`

Department :

```
id_department, name_department
```

Branch :

```
id_branch, name_branch
```

Staff :

```
id_staff, email, fk_branch, fk_department, status
```

I have a list of departments and their respective branches :

```
id_branch, id_department
1,2
1,3
2,5
3,2
```

I want to filter this list, and get only those deparments with active users in  the company.

I actually got to a result, however i think i am overcomplicating things, specially in the GROUP BY part, i think that might not be necessary.

```
WITH dept_managers_in_country AS
    (
        SELECT
            (
                SELECT 
                    id_staff 
                FROM dsv_global.staff 
                WHERE email = s.email
            ) as id_staff,
            s.email,
            dm.fk_branch,
            dm.fk_department
        FROM dsv_one_access.databases_access.department_module dm
        --Getting dept. manager fk_staff
        INNER JOIN dsv_one_access.databases_access.u_staff_modules usm
        ON usm.u_staff_modules = dm.fk_u_staff_modules
        --Getting dept. manager email
        INNER JOIN dsv_one_access.databases_access.staff s
        ON s.id_staff = usm.fk_staff

        WHERE s.fk_country = 6
    ),
    --departments current user has
    depts_in_charge AS
    (
        SELECT 
            fk_branch, 
            fk_department 
        FROM dept_managers_in_country
        WHERE id_staff = 960
        --won't work proced if user is not 
        --dept. manager and line below is removed   
        UNION SELECT 0,0
    )
SELECT 
        dic.fk_branch,
        dic.fk_department,
        d.name_department,
        d.complete_name_dept,
        --Choosing dept. manager in department
        (
            SELECT 
                id_staff AS id_supervisor,
                email 
            FROM dept_managers_in_country  
            WHERE  fk_branch = dic.fk_branch AND fk_department = dic.fk_department
            FOR JSON PATH
        ) as supervisors,
        'Department without active users' as comments

    FROM depts_in_charge dic

    INNER JOIN dsv_global.departments d
    ON dic.fk_department = d.id_department

    LEFT JOIN dsv_global.staff s
    on s.fk_branch = dic.fk_branch
    AND s.fk_department = dic.fk_department


    WHERE @level_view = 'department_manager'
    GROUP BY dic.fk_branch,
        dic.fk_department,
        d.name_department,
        d.complete_name_dept
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.status = 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  = 0
```

The result is :

```
fk_branch   fk_department   name_department complete_name_dept  supervisors comments
4   66  FIA Freight import[{"id_supervisor":960,"email":"email@x.com"}] Department without active users
```

Comment: I am confused why your query is so complex with a CTE and union. You may need to update with more specification as query indicates additional logic. Your post shows two lookup tables. So all you need is to query the last table for *only those departments with active users in the company*: `select distinct fk_branch, fk_department ... from staff where status = 'ACTIVE'`. Also your title even conflicts with quoted objective.

Comment: Please have a look at [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, if your solution works, then what is the problem? If you need a code review, there is a [dedicated StackExhange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Comment: I agree with Parfait, where the title contradicts part of the body of your description. One says "not" while other says "in". If wanting to identify just the branch/dept combos without active users, and assuming that all combos are filled with something, then:    select distinct s.fk_branch, s.fk_department
from staff s
where s.status <> 'active'
except
select distinct s.fk_branch, s.fk_department
from staff s
where s.status = 'active'